How to change java file behaviour to use 2 character indentation
If I create a C file I get 2 character indentation which is what I want.  However, if I create a java file, eg Hello.java then I am getting 4 character indentation.  And I can't work out why.
My .emacs file:
(custom-set-variables
 '(column-number-mode t)
 '(tab-width 2)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(initial-scratch-message nil)
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 )

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)


Check c-basic-offset, c-default-style, and c-style-alist.
The default style for java is:
("java" (c-basic-offset . 4) (c-comment-only-line-offset 0 . 0)
  (c-offsets-alist (inline-open . 0) (topmost-intro-cont . +)
                   (statement-block-intro . +) (knr-argdecl-intro . 5)
                   (substatement-open . +) (substatement-label . +) (label . +)
                   (statement-case-open . +) (statement-cont . +)
                   (arglist-intro . c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren)
                   (arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                   (brace-list-intro first c-lineup-2nd-brace-entry-in-arglist
                                     c-lineup-class-decl-init-+ +)
                   (access-label . 0) (inher-cont . c-lineup-java-inher)
                   (func-decl-cont . c-lineup-java-throws)))

If you just want to use 2 character indentation,
(setq c-basic-offset 2)

